# c++ permission slip idiom?

Tags: c++, templates, encapsulation, type-safety

I'm doing a university programming project, cutting details short I'm making a game dev framework which I want to be very hard to get wrong (plenty of static and type safety)

I found myself with a problem which I though required the Attorney-Client idiom, wherein only an Actor can create a Component, but I had some uncomfortable and foolable hoops to jump through with derived component classes and having other uses for an Attorney (mostly limiting creation, but also some management of objects and event handling)

My solution in the end was to have an Attorney-Client like class for each action I wanted to permit, a Permission slip, allowing a bit more specificity on why the slip is being passed and why it is needed to avoid misuse.

It allows a limited number of uses (in my particular case only 1 use), this was to ensure a permission slip passed to a component could not be used to create other components and other problems of the likes.

example of implementation

```
template<typename T, typename T_Permit>
class PermissionSlip {
public:

    PermissionSlip(const PermissionSlip& t_other) = delete;
    ~PermissionSlip() {
    }

    // use permission slip
    void use() {
        assert(m_uses != 0 && "No more uses permitted.");
        --m_uses;
    }

    unsigned int getUses() { return m_uses; }
private:

    // allow T to create permission slip
    friend typename T;
    PermissionSlip() : m_uses{ 1 } {}
    PermissionSlip(unsigned int t_uses) : m_uses{ t_uses }
    unsigned int m_uses{ 1 };
};
```

example of use

```
class B;

class P_ConstructB;
typedef PermissionSlip<A, P_ConstructB> ConstructBPermit;

class A {
public:

    A() {}
    ~A() {}

    template<typename T>
    void createB() {
        ConstructBPermit permit;
        B* myB = new T( permit );
        m_myBs.push_back(myB);
    }
private:

    std::vector<B*> m_myBs;
};

class B {
public:

    B(ConstructBPermit& t_permit) { t_permit.use(); }
    ~B() {}
};


class C : B {
public:

    C(ConstructBPermit& t_permit) : B{ t_permit } {}
    ~C() {}
};
```

I guess the question I'm asking is if I've missed some important features of the Attorney-Client idiom, or missed important pitfalls of this system, relatedly if there is a more idiomatic way to approach this.

edit: forgot constructer in createB use example
further edit: value of m_uses was useless on passing, amended to only be passed as reference. Also some minor syntax errors
even further edit: append a getUses function to permission slip

Comment: To be honest this `PermissionSlip` class seems to be completely useless. If you want to limit count of class instance that could be created (I guess this is what you are actually trying to do) then it would be better to derive B from some `InstanceCounter` checking number of created instances in default constructor.

Comment: Now you mention that I just realized that the permission slip can be passed and used without the passed slip remembering its been used, I'll fix that now by passing it around as a reference.
The actual intention is that slip can only be used once, so when A gives C the permit to construct B, it can only pass it to B, it can't pass it to another instance to create another component.

Comment: oh and I failed to address it in my comment, but the initial idea was I wanted only an actor to be able to construct any kind of component, while allowing external component derived classes and avoiding using friend so other contributors will not treat actor like it can mess with the innards of a component.

Comment: I've seen and used the concept of permission or access tags before, but I'm not sure about the use count addition. It's not clear what sort of problem you're trying to prevent with it, but I note that any given class or function is either allowed to create zero permissions or as many as it wants.

Comment: For my current use a bool would do just as well, I just figured to use a number type instead for flexibilities sake. Cases where it could be useful as an example might be, an objectA wishes to fire an event, the event centers around a manager and its resources, objectA in order to fire the event requests permits from manager which then dertermines how many event fires are appropriate for its resources. of course you'd want a getUses function in order for that to be useful without catching an exception